# IE11 minlength or pattern not validating + bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11

is there a way to validate minlength on my field in IE11? seems like is being ignored, I am using bootstrap 4.5 to validate my form also.

```
<input class="form-control" id="portVal" required="" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" data-dpmaxz-eid="5" minlength="6">
```

However, seems like email pattern is validating email correctly, how can I update `[0-9]*` to configure a minimum number?

```
<input class="form-control" id="sEmail" required="" type="text" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" data-dpmaxz-eid="4" data-nl-label="Email" data-nl-bindto="xpath" data-nl-ismandatory="true" data-nl-xpath="@email">
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the regex, i was testing something and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't support the `minlength` attribute. You'll have to use the regex `.{6,}`, which matches 6 or more characters:

```html
<form>
<input class="form-control" id="portVal" type="text" pattern=".{6,}" data-dpmaxz-eid="5" required>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```